# How to use value of Variable from void method?

Tags: java, selenium, junit

I have some void test which getting value from website:

```
  @Test
        public void MemberEditInfo(){
        ...
         WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("Member_Email"));
         String elementval = element.getAttribute("value");
         }
```

How can I use value of String `elementval` in another class(the method is void and does not return any value since if it would return a value then Junit wouldn't work)?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot return values in a function with a `void` return type. Try changing it to a static value or calling a static method in another class. You might end up having to define a new class for this.

Answer (score 2):

Just wrap

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("Member_Email"));
String elementval = element.getAttribute("value");
```

Into a method, let's say

```
public static String returnAttributeValue(driver_variable_type driver, String attr, String attrName) {
   driver.findElement(By.id(attr)).getAttribute(attrName);
}
```

And just use this method in both: your test and somewhere you need it.

Comment: Before each new log in to the website, I will need to make an additional test which will be receiving Email value for the user?

Comment: This statement should have some return var. It should be some string?

Comment: This method must return a result of type String ( from eclipse).

Answer (score 1):

I don't use JUnit so if you can't return something other than void, one option is to create a static class property in this class and put the `String` into it. From the other class you just reference it.

In this class, `Test1`

```
static String elementVal;

@Test
public void MemberEditInfo()
{
    ...
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("Member_Email"));
    this.elementVal = element.getAttribute("value");
}
```

In your other class, `Test2`

```
String elementVal = Test1.elementVal;
```

Comment: I guess it's a good approach, but when Test1 ended variable elementval in test2 have Null value. How do you think, can I save value of element val for the case, when Test1 is closed?

Comment: To be honest, best practice is that tests should not rely on data from each other. You really should find a better, different way to do this. Each test should be independent and should be able to run in any order.

Comment: Thank you, I will find another decision.